# What is the easiest way to defeat two Hewdraw heads at once?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

To unlock a panel, I need to defeat two of the Hewdraw heads at once on any intensity. I have tried a few times already, and it seems that wearing two heads down and using an ultimate attack doesn't defeat them. Has anyone done this yet, or do you have an idea, weapon type I should use or strategy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played the level on 0.0 difficulty. I used a Knuckle Staff (Most staves will probably do the trick though), then I just fired off both special attack orbs once he was targetable.

Once I used the attacks, it knocked both heads off. Not too hard at 0.0 difficulty.

Comment: All staffs have identical special attacks (including damage). This also applies to other weapon types, the only difference depends on what weapon type you're using.

Answer (score 1):

On **0.0 intensity**, use any **club** or **staff** weapon's **special (power) attack** by tapping the one of the two **blue orbs** at the bottom touchscreen (they regenerate after use). 
This attack will damage **all three heads**.

Three or so should be enough. You can hit each head with a charged attack and then use two special attacks.

Comment: Any specific club recommendations? I've got a Capricorn, Atlas, and Earthmaul here, and none seem to do a particularly good job hitting two at once.

Comment: I tried using the Earthmaul Club for it. It has a wide attack, but you have to do it perfectly to do it. I just ended up using a feather for that panel.

Comment: By "special attack" I meant the Blue Orbs that clear the entire screen in Aerial Missions.

Comment: I thought his answer was good. ok not the best description but the answer above it was less accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. I just played the level, and found out that when you wait long enough, Lady Palutena says she is charging an attack and Pit says he can defeat the three heads himself. But if you wait longer, she will fire the shot and destroy all three heads at once!

Comment: Actually, I've tried that already, but it didn't work. Sorry...